# Consequences of syntactically invalid names

Tags: r, naming-conventions, read.table

The `read.table` family (`read.table`, `read.csv`, `read.delim` et al) has the argument `check.names` with the following explanation:

> logical. If `TRUE` then the names of the variables in the data frame are checked to ensure that they are syntactically valid variable names. If necessary they are adjusted (by `make.names`) so that they are, and also to ensure that there are no duplicates.

Say I have loaded a data frame containing syntactically invalid column names. Is there any other consequence apart from having to access a specific column by name using the `` ` `` character?

Comment: `check.names` not only checks whether the names are valid, but it reformats them if they aren't. For example, if you have a column called `Fiscal Year` it will be renamed to `Fiscal_Year` if `check.names = TRUE`. Spaces can just be inconvenient, but there are other characters that could actually cause issues, like a leading comma.

Comment: I am aware that check.names fixes invalid names. Could you elaborate on the actual issues that could be caused by other characters?

Comment: Most functions expect valid column names and may error out with invalid names (especially those that use non-standard evaluation). If you choose invalid names, you do so at your own risk. You should thoroughly test any functions you wish to use to see if they work with invalid names (or just use valid names and make your life much easier).

Answer (score 4):

Check out `help(make.names)` to understand what it is doing and why.

> A syntactically valid name consists of letters, numbers and the dot or
>   underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot not followed
>   by a number. Names such as ".2way" are not valid, and neither are the
>   reserved words.
>
> The definition of a letter depends on the current locale, but only
>   ASCII digits are considered to be digits.
>
> The character "X" is prepended if necessary. All invalid characters
>   are translated to ".". A missing value is translated to "NA". Names
>   which match R keywords have a dot appended to them. Duplicated values
>   are altered by make.unique.

The big ones that will trip you up are blank column names (``` df$`` ``` gives an error) and repeated column names (`df$val` will return the first `val` column result only).

Outside of that, if you pass this data.frame to a function that is expecting a data.frame with valid names, you will likely get errors, and perhaps silent ones that are hard to detect.